# Sort table in HTML by column with date values desc using only javaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Is it possible to make sorting function using only javaScript, without any other library for sorting?

Let's say I have one table, and it's first column that has date values in this format: MM/dd/yyyy. Table has two more columns, like this:

```
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/08/2015</td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Raven</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>05/04/2015</td>
        <td>Test Name 4</td>
        <td>Raven 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr/>
        <td>01/08/2017</td>
        <td>Test Name 2</td>
        <td>PCT</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Would it be possible to lets say add one button, and on click event sort rows by values in Date column?

I have to accomplish this using only plain javaScript and HTML, so no jQuery unfortunately :(

Comment: Of course its possible but why do you have to do that without jquery or any other javascript plugin. It will require a lot load of code. You can do that with just 1 line of code with jquery sortable.

Comment: @EfeÖzazar you know that magical word - clients... haha it is a request... They like to see us suffering I guess... I know it's super easy with jQuery for example, just few lines... but I have no choice...

Comment: Should the data be in a tbody element? (It would simplify the sort if the header row didn't belong to the same parent...)

Comment: @nemo_87 they hate us and we hate them :D then start writing if you stuck anywhere update your question with your code. I will keep track of it. I dknt have time to write it all but i will help if i can.

Comment: @nnnnnn well we can change it to tbody, if it will simplify it... I am still bad with plain javaScript, so I don't know what can I do with tbody, but I will research a bit. Thanks for idea :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a little something I whipped up to give you some ideas. Obviously you could extend this to sort by other data types.

I've "cheated" on the date comparisons by just changing the string format date directly to an eight-digit number in the form `20140312` from `"12/03/2014"` - note that I've assumed the date input format is `dd/mm/yyyy`, so if for some reason you're actually using `mm/dd/yyyy` you'll have to tweak the `convertDate()` function.

Also I've introduced a `<tbody>` into your table so that I can just sort the data rows and completely ignore the header row.

```js
function convertDate(d) {
  var p = d.split("/");
  return +(p[2]+p[1]+p[0]);
}

function sortByDate() {
  var tbody = document.querySelector("#results tbody");
  // get trs as array for ease of use
  var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));
  
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {
    return convertDate(a.cells[0].innerHTML) - convertDate(b.cells[0].innerHTML);
  });
  
  rows.forEach(function(v) {
    tbody.appendChild(v); // note that .appendChild() *moves* elements
  });
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", sortByDate);
```

```html
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>04/04/2015</td>
        <td>Test Name 2</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>09/08/2017</td>
        <td>Test Name 5</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/08/2015</td>
        <td>Test Name 4</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>05/04/2015</td>
        <td>Test Name 3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/08/2017</td>
        <td>Test Name 6</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21/03/2014</td>
        <td>Test Name 1</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button>Sort by date</button>
```

Comment: nice solution! :) It's not working for me, because I have one more button on the page, so I guess it doesn't pick the right one, but I can change last line and it should be ok :) Thank you for this! :) @nnnnnn

Comment: Well sure, the button wasn't really part of the solution, it was part of the demo. Having the table ID hardcoded within the sort function isn't really ideal either, but it was just a quick way to get it up and running so that I could get the sort concept across. You can tidy it up in your real project, and make the sort direction a parameter of the function, etc.

Comment: yes I agree, later I can just change it, but the most important is that has correct functionality :D thanks :D @nnnnnn

Comment: I don't see how this statement 'tbody.appendChild(v);' removes all elements and starts from scratch.

Comment: @Nguaial - It doesn't *remove* elements, it *moves* them. Note that that statement is inside a loop, so it moves all rows, one at a time.

Comment: @nnnnnn - The word appendChild() should not be used if that is the case.  That is so misleading. It should use the word something like moveChild().