# Sort HTML table with date range column using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

like if a column contains dates 9/17/2018 - 9/21/22018 in the first row and 9/30/2018 - 10/12/2018 in second row etc, need help with Sorting such columns from the earliest date range.
My table right now:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="sortable" 
id="myTable2" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #000000;">
<thead>

<th style="text-align: center;" width="200"><b>Pay Week</b></th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="200"><b>Date of Intermittent Leave 
Event</b> </th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="400"><b>Pay Instruction</b></th>

</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">8/5/2018 - 8/11/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">8/8/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="400">3.0 hour(s) unpaid/ PTO 
(FMLA)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">8/12/2018 - 8/18/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">8/18/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="400">4.0 hour(s) unpaid/ PTO 
(FMLA)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/9/2018 - 9/15/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/12/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="400">7.0 hour(s) unpaid/ PTO 
(FMLA)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/9/2018 - 9/15/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/13/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="400">7.0 hour(s) unpaid/ PTO 
(FMLA)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/9/2018 - 9/15/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/14/2018</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="400">7.0 hour(s) unpaid/ PTO 
(FMLA)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/3/2017 - 9/9/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/10/2017 - 9/16/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/17/2017 - 9/23/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">9/24/2017 - 9/30/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">10/1/2017 - 10/7/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">10/8/2017 - 10/14/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">10/15/2017 - 10/21/2017</td>
  <td style="text-align: center;" width="200">N/A - Continuous</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" width="400"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button>Sort Pay Week</button>

<script>
  function convertDate(d) {
    var str = d.split("-", 1);
    var p = str.split("/");
    return +(p[2] + p[0] + p[1]);
  }

  function sortByDate() {
    var tbody = document.querySelector("#results tbody");
    // get trs as array for ease of use
    var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      return convertDate(a.cells[0].innerHTML) - convertDate(b.cells[0].innerHTML);
    });

    rows.forEach(function(v) {
      tbody.appendChild(v); // note that .appendChild() *moves* elements
    });
  }

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", sortByDate);

</script>
```

After the first column is sorted, the second column's values are jumbled, how to sort just the rows that contain a date and not NA-Continuous cells?

Comment: What libraries/frameworks are you using to make the table sortable? I see you have `class="sortable"` in your HTML, but HTML itself doesn't implement sortable tables.

Comment: Are you using static html 
or these rows dynamically added through javascript?

Comment: @AagamJain Rows get added dynamically using apex:repeat tag of Salesforce's visualforce. This is the rendered output on browser, but javascript works with HTML table element in visualforce

Comment: @jacob that class Sortable is something I experimented from google search, not working exactly.

Comment: tried this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp but does not work in my case coz its Date range columns. Then I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889423/sort-table-in-html-by-column-with-date-values-desc-using-only-javascript with tweak in script function convertDate(d) {
          var str = d.split("-",1);
            var p = str.split("/");
          return +(p[2]+p[0]+p[1]);
        }

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your last attempted JavaScript and what did/did not work with that attempt? It's far easier to help with specific problems than an entire solution.

Comment: I did edit the question along with the error I am getting.

Comment: Try changing  var tbody = document.querySelector("#results tbody"); to  var tbody = document.querySelector("#myTable2 tbody");

Comment: @duppu plz check my answer and mark it as accepted if it works for you.
Thanks :)

Comment: @AagamJain please check my comment on your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it for you:

```
function convertDate(d) {
    var str = d.split("-", 1)[0].trim();
    var p = str.split("/");
    return new Date(p[2] + "-"+p[0]+"-" + p[1]);
  }

  function sortByDate() {
    var tbody = document.querySelector("#myTable2 tbody");
    // get trs as array for ease of use
    var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      return convertDate(a.cells[0].innerHTML) - convertDate(b.cells[0].innerHTML);
    });

    rows.forEach(function(v) {
      tbody.appendChild(v); // note that .appendChild() *moves* elements
    });
  }

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", sortByDate);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/agamj474/pen/KxGEXV.

Comment: only works with first and last rows, the rest of the rows in between are not sorted, I did check that in your codepen too

Comment: @duppu sorry for delay in response. I have edited the answer and link as well.
Please check and let me know if any concern.

Comment: awesome, it works! Thank you @Aagam Jain! I did vote up the answer but it is not recorded as I have reputation less than 15, coz I am a newbie.

Comment: No worries bro :)