# JavaScript sort function is not sorting and I cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web app which I am new at but I have been developing apps for many years for the business forms industry so am not new at development but am pretty new at web dev.

Below is a stripped down sample to show my problem that I am running on Chrome.   I picked up a solution from [Sort table in HTML by column with date values desc using only javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889423/sort-table-in-html-by-column-with-date-values-desc-using-only-javascript) and removed the 'by date' part to make it easier. The problem seems to be in the `rows.sort()` part as it doesn't seem to be sorting the array at all.

The comments in the code that start with `//'by MPG'` are my comments and the others from the downloaded code. I do understand that jquery can do this but I want to stay with JavaScript as I really dont want to load and learn another language.

```js
function calcbal() {
  sortByDate();
}

// Also I've introduced a <tbody> into your table so that I can just sort the data rows and completely ignore the header row.
function sortByDate() {
  var tbody = document.querySelector("#cashflow tbody");

  var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr")); // get trs as array for ease of use
  console.log("rows b4 sort: ");
  console.log(rows); //'by MPG' added for debugging
  rows.sort(); //'by MPG' i think this line is where the problem is. ** * PROBLEM ** *
    console.log("rows after sort: ");
  console.log(rows); //'by MPG' added for debugging
  rows.forEach(function(v) {
    tbody.appendChild(v); // note that .appendChild() *moves* elements
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells: show;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  width: 100%;
  <!--874px;
  -->table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: .84em;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: .9em;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="calcbal()">Sort 1st col</button>
  <table id=cashflow contenteditable>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="40px" contenteditable="false">Sortcell</th>
        <!--0-->
        <th width="115px" contenteditable="false">AccountName</th>
        <!--1-->
        <th width="40px" contenteditable="false">PayDate</th>
        <!--2-->
        <th width="40px" contenteditable="false">DueDate</th>
        <!--3-->
        <th width="32px" contenteditable="false">Cycle</th>
        <!--4-->
        <th width="34px" contenteditable="false">Method</td>
          <!--5-->
          <th width="41px" contenteditable="false">AutoPay</th>
          <!--6-->
          <th width="150px" contenteditable="false">Comment</th>
          <!--7-->
          <th width="45px" contenteditable="false">PymtDue</th>
          <!--8-->
          <th width="34px" contenteditable="false">Budget</th>
          <!--9-->
          <th width="66px" contenteditable="false">PymtSched</th>
          <!--10-->
          <th width="38px" contenteditable="false">Balance</th>
          <!--11-->
          <th width="200px" contenteditable="false">URL</th>
          <!--12-->
          <th width="39px" contenteditable="false">AcctBal</th>
          <!--13-->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>200101</td>
        <td>Bank Account xxxx</td>
        <td>01/01/20</td>
        <td>01/01/20</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>https://www.</td>
        <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>210401</td>
        <td>APLACE4SPACE</td>
        <td>04/01/21</td>
        <td>04/01/21</td>
        <td>Monthly</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>79</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>79</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>https://www.aplace4space.com/</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>210331</td>
        <td>RENT TO DOUG</td>
        <td>03/31/21</td>
        <td>03/31/21</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>https://www.</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll have to create a sort comparator function so that you can compare a row to another row and tell `.sort()` what the ordering should be.

Comment: The default for `.sort` if you don't pass it a function is [UTF-16 code unit values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), which is almost certainly not what you want. Also, jQuery isn't a language (not even an embedded DSL like JSX) it's just a library.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others in the comments you need to supply a function to the compareFunction parameter. Otherwise the sort function compares the string representation of your rows which is the same for all rows: `[object HTMLTableRowElement]`.

In the example below I use `firstElementChild` to get the first element of the row. It seems like it's filled with an integer value so i converted the textual content to an integer. This integer can than be used to compare 2 rows.

See documentation on [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
function calcbal() {
  sortByDate();
}

function sortByDate() {
  var tbody = document.querySelector("#cashflow tbody");
  var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));

  //Add a compare function to the compareFunction paramter that defines how to sort the array.
  rows = rows.sort((row1, row2) => {
    return parseInt(row1.firstElementChild.textContent) - parseInt(row2.firstElementChild.textContent)
  });

  rows.forEach(function(v) {
    tbody.appendChild(v);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells: show;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  width: 100%;
  <!--874px;
  -->table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: .84em;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: .9em;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="calcbal()">Sort 1st col</button>
  <table id=cashflow contenteditable>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="40px" contenteditable="false">Sortcell</th>
        <!--0-->
        <th width="115px" contenteditable="false">AccountName</th>
        <!--1-->
        <th width="40px" contenteditable="false">PayDate</th>
        <!--2-->
        <th width="40px" contenteditable="false">DueDate</th>
        <!--3-->
        <th width="32px" contenteditable="false">Cycle</th>
        <!--4-->
        <th width="34px" contenteditable="false">Method</td>
          <!--5-->
          <th width="41px" contenteditable="false">AutoPay</th>
          <!--6-->
          <th width="150px" contenteditable="false">Comment</th>
          <!--7-->
          <th width="45px" contenteditable="false">PymtDue</th>
          <!--8-->
          <th width="34px" contenteditable="false">Budget</th>
          <!--9-->
          <th width="66px" contenteditable="false">PymtSched</th>
          <!--10-->
          <th width="38px" contenteditable="false">Balance</th>
          <!--11-->
          <th width="200px" contenteditable="false">URL</th>
          <!--12-->
          <th width="39px" contenteditable="false">AcctBal</th>
          <!--13-->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>200101</td>
        <td>Bank Account xxxx</td>
        <td>01/01/20</td>
        <td>01/01/20</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>https://www.</td>
        <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>210401</td>
        <td>APLACE4SPACE</td>
        <td>04/01/21</td>
        <td>04/01/21</td>
        <td>Monthly</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>79</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>79</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>https://www.aplace4space.com/</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>210331</td>
        <td>RENT TO DOUG</td>
        <td>03/31/21</td>
        <td>03/31/21</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>https://www.</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```